# Textview getting recreated when timer is paused when returning from second activity

Tags: java, android

I have a weird problem regarding android Textview. I have a timer running on a runnable with a toggle button to start and pause/stop it which is in the main activity. I have another activity to do other stuff. In order not to recreate an new instance of textview when I return back to the main activity I have declared it static. When the timer is running I can go forward and back between the two activities and the textview updates as it should. However if i pause the timer and then to next activity and back to main the textview gets reset. Why is this? If it works when it is running then surely it should work for when it is paused.

Comment: When you switch activities, the old activity could be garbage collected if Android is running low on memory. While the timer is running, Android is prioritizing it and not removing it from memory. Please try testing on a device with more memory and report if the textview is reset everytime when switching activity with the timer paused.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have another device to hand. If this was a memory issue then this could be an issue from device to device. Lets say this is the issue is there a way to force it to keep the data. Alternatively is there a better way to keep the instance of textview. I have tried onSaveInstanceState but only really works for screen rotation and not between activities

Comment: Whenever you switch activities, you should persist any data you want the the user to be able to access in the future. You could do this by saving the the TextView value in a SharePref or database. My preferred method is a Singleton. If possible, reduce the number of activities in your app and use fragments instead. This way, you stay in the same activity and can share elements such as the timer between fragments easily. Hope this helps!

Comment: That all sounds a bit overkill especially for a novice like me. What I did was create a few statics and then used the onPause and onResume events to set and reset things accordingly. Its really simple and works really well. Simpler solutions are always the best as as the fancy methods are a pain to debug later on, but thats another story. Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve your issue! I'm not too advanced myself but you are right, simpler is better!